# Php : Separate file content into different files

Tags: php, html, file, file-handling, filehandle

I have this file

```
1 + 3 = 4
0 + 0 = 0
1 + 2 = 3
1 / 1 = 1
2 * 3 = 6
```

I want to separate the (firstNum, secondNum, operationUsed(+,-,*,/), and result) into 4 different files

Comment: parse it then use file_put_contents, but why?

Comment: Easiest way is to explode on newline, then loop that result - and explode on spaces - then append each value in that second `explode()` in separate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you would ever need this but here you go

- Use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the file into an array
- Then use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string by spaces
- Then push each of the values to the set of values using a loop ([foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php))
- Then [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them and save to file with [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
<?php
// read
$array = file('original.txt');

// parse
$set = [
 'firstNum' => [],
 'secondNum' => [],
 'operationUsed' => [],
 'result' => [],
];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $value = explode(' ', $value);
    
    $set['firstNum'][] = $value[0];
    $set['secondNum'][] = $value[1];
    $set['operationUsed'][] = $value[2];
    $set['result'][] = $value[3];
}

// write
file_put_contents('firstNum.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $set['firstNum']));
file_put_contents('secondNum.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $set['secondNum']));
file_put_contents('operationUsed.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $set['operationUsed']));
file_put_contents('result.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $set['result']));
```